# JQuery iterate through JSON array and insert into dynamic HTML SELECT

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, select

For the life of me, I have no idea why this isn't working - I've tried multiple ways of trying to insert the JSON data into the `<option>` code each time it doesn't work like that - it merely outputs the HTML text and not inside a `<select>` drop down

```
$.getJSON( "group.asp", function( data ) {
    $('#msgBox').html($('#msgBox').html() + '<div class="table-row"><div class="table-col-l">Name:</div><div class="table-col-r"><select id="name1"><option>SELECT</option>')
    $(data).each(function(index, element) {
        console.log(element)
        $('#msgBox').html($('#msgBox').html() + '<option>'+element.name+'</option>');
    });
    $('#msgBox').html($('#msgBox').html() + '</select></div></div>')
})
```

I've tried creating it as a separate variable that is inserted after the `.each` function but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do a proper string concatenation before using `.html()`,

```
$.getJSON( "group.asp", function( data ) {
    var str = $('#msgBox').html();
    str += '<div class="table-row"><div class="table-col-l">Name:</div><div class="table-col-r"><select id="name1"><option>SELECT</option>';
    $(data).each(function(index, element) {
        str += '<option>'+element.name+'</option>';
    });
    str += '</select></div></div>';
    $('#msgBox').html(str);
})
```

Comment: That works perfectly, the only thing I didn't think of trying (and really should have!).  Will need this for other projects so more than one issue solved in one go.  Many thanks!

Comment: @Hyperjase Glad to help! :)